# Spring DI: from XML to Annotations

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

For merely educational reasons I'm trying to explore the differences between using Annotations or XML configuration for DI with Spring.

In order tot do that, I have an example of a Messager App which can use different implementations to do different kind of jobs (send an email, send a sms).

Using a test class I can get a bean from the factory, injected with a different implementation if I want.

This is how it looks:

IMessageService.java

```
    public interface IMessageService {

       public void sendMessage(String message, String recipient);

    }
```

EmailMessageServiceImpl.java

```
public class EmailMessageServiceImpl implements IMessageService {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String message, String recipient) {
        //Validations email, etc.
        System.out.println(String.format("EMAIL Message: %s. Recipient: %s", message, recipient));
    }

}
```

SMSMessageServiceImpl.java

```
public class SMSMessageServiceImpl implements IMessageService {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String message, String recipient) {
        //Phone validations
        System.out.println(String.format("SMS message: %s. Sent to: %s", message, recipient));
    }

}
```

App.java

```
    public class App {

        private IMessageService messageService;

        public void processMessages(String message, String recipient) {

            messageService.sendMessage(message, recipient);

        }

        public void setMessageService(IMessageService messageService) {
            this.messageService = messageService;
        }

}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <!--    Declaring the App and injecting two different implementations of IMessageService-->
<bean id="appEmail" class="org.invenio.tic.holamundospring.App">
    <property name="messageService" ref="emailImpl"/>
</bean>

<bean id="appSMS" class="org.invenio.tic.holamundospring.App">
    <property name="messageService" ref="smsImpl"/>
</bean>


<!--    Declaring the beans with the implementations-->
<bean id="emailImpl" class="org.invenio.tic.holamundospring.service.EmailMessageServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="smsImpl" class="org.invenio.tic.holamundospring.service.SMSMessageServiceImpl"/>
```

And finally the test class
Main.java

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        App app = (App) context.getBean("appEmail");
        app.processMessages("Hi, this is an email", "info@invenio.org");

        app = (App) context.getBean("appSMS");
        app.processMessages("This is an SMS", "88100452");

    }

}
```

This prints:

```
    EMAIL Message: Hi, this is an email. Recipient: info@invenio.org
    SMS message: This is an SMS. Sent to: 88100452
```

When I try to do this with Annotations, using the Autowiring and Autodiscovery features of Spring, I'm loosing the ability to get the App with different Implementations, since the Annotation @Autowired let me choose the implementation I want, but it will be hardcoded to the App.java class.

App.java

```
    @Component
    public class App {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emailServiceImpl")
    private IMessageService messageService;

    public void processMessages(String message, String recipient) {

        messageService.sendMessage(message, recipient);

    }

    public void setMessageService(IMessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

}
```

Is there a way around this issue? like passing the qualifier name in a parameter or something that let me, in runtime, change the implementation of the MessageService?

Or is this one of the cons of using Annotations?

Thanks
-Alejandro.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `@Qualifier("emailServiceImpl")` to `@Qualifier("emailImpl")`, as you have defined in your applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Once I start using annotations all the bean definitions gets removed from the xml since I use the autodiscover feature:

<context: component-scan package="my.package"/>
<context: annotation-config/>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using app constructor like this:

**Configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.anno") //your package goes here
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "appEmail")

    public App appEmail(@Qualifier("EmailMessageServiceImpl") IMessageService messageService) {
        return new App(messageService);
    }

    @Bean(name = "appSMS")
    public App appSms(@Qualifier("SMSMessageServiceImpl") IMessageService messageService) {
        return new App(messageService);
    }
}
```

**App class:**

```
@Component

    public class App {

        private IMessageService messageService;

        public App() {
        }
        public App(IMessageService messageService) {
            this.messageService = messageService;
        }
        public void processMessages(String message, String recipient) {

            messageService.sendMessage(message, recipient);

        }

        public void setMessageService(IMessageService messageService) {
            this.messageService = messageService;
        }

    }
```

**Services Classes:**

```
@Service("SMSMessageServiceImpl")
public class SMSMessageServiceImpl implements IMessageService {

    public void sendMessage(String message, String recipient) {
        // Phone validations
        System.out.println(String.format("SMS message: %s. Sent to: %s", message, recipient));
    }

}

@Service("EmailMessageServiceImpl")
public class EmailMessageServiceImpl implements IMessageService {

    public void sendMessage(String message, String recipient) {
        // Validations email, etc.
        System.out.println(String.format("EMAIL Message: %s. Recipient: %s", message, recipient));
    }

}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        App app = (App) context.getBean("appEmail");
        app.processMessages("Hi, this is an email", "info@invenio.org");

        app = (App) context.getBean("appSMS");
        app.processMessages("This is an SMS", "88100452");

}

}
```

Hope this can help.